# Steam game price history using Steam API

Tags: steam-web-api

I would like to get price history of a specific Steam game.

I know that I can get current price information of a game like this (example with Portal 2):

```
GET https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?filters=price_overview&appids=620
{
    "620": {
        "success": true,
        "data": {
            "price_overview": {
                "currency": "USD",
                "initial": 999,
                "final": 999,
                "discount_percent": 0,
                "initial_formatted": "",
                "final_formatted": "$9.99"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And there is `https://steamcommunity.com/market/pricehistory` to get price history of a specific item of a game.

Is there a way to get price history of a game itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no price history API directly from Steam.

You need to use third-party providers or record the prices yourself. [Isthereanydeal](https://itad.docs.apiary.io/#reference/game/prices) might be helpful.